# Html Page Template in Asp.net Web Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

My company has outsourced the UI design to another company.That company gave us the html templates. Currently, the way we are doing to display the data is that we call the web service from jquery ajax and web service request the collection of objects from Data Acess Layer(Eg. Collection of Customer Objects). After that, the collection is converted to json string, and return as result to Jquery Ajax. Then, Jquery took the values from json string replace accordingly in html string and append to div. That html string is the template provided by outsource company. Below is the exmaple of Jquery.

```
function ShowAllTransactions() {
try
{

    var isBest = "false";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Transaction.asmx/GetTransactionRecords",
        data: "{'categoryID':'" + categores +"' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            GetTransactions(msg);
        }
    }).done(initProductInfo);
    }
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
}

var GetTransactions = function (msg) {
    var p = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
    var str = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        var OrderCreateDateTime = p[i].OrderCreateDateTime;
        str += "<ul class=\"transitem\">";
        str += "<li class=\"itemdate\">" + OrderCreateDateTime + "  </li> ";
        str += "</ul> <div class=\"clear\"></div>";
       }
    str += "<div class=\"clear\"></div> <div class=\"endline\"></div>";

    $("#records").empty().append(str);
}
```

Normally, html strings are very long and difficult to maintain and troubleshoot. Is there any better way to solve this? We are using Entity Framework for DAL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx) looks like a nice article about using `jquery templates`. Not sure how it works though, because I never used it.
I use a similar approach, but the templates are actually a mixture of HTML and Javascript. The templates look similar with [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx).

This is a bit of code that parses the template:

```
$.fn.parseTemplate = function (data) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    var str = (this).html();
    //alert(str);
    var _tmplCache = {}
    var err = "";
    try {
        var func = _tmplCache[str];
        if (!func) {
            var strFunc =
            "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +
                        "with(obj){p.push('" +
            str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
               .replace(/'(?=[^\$]*\$>)/g, "\t")
               .split("'").join("\\'")
               .split("\t").join("'")
               .replace(/<\$=(.+?)\$>/g, "',$1,'")
               .split("<$").join("');")
               .split("$>").join("p.push('")
               + "');}return p.join('');";

            //alert(strFunc);
            //console.log(strFunc);
            func = new Function("obj", strFunc);
            _tmplCache[str] = func;
        }
        return func(data);
    } catch (e) { err = e.message; }
    return "ERROR: " + err.toString();
}
```

This is an example of a template (the script is ignored by the browser because of the type):

```
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/template">
<$
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
$>
<div><$= obj[i] $></div>
<$
}
$>
</script>
```

This is how I use the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadDataIntoHtml() {
  var data = ["Javascript", "HTML", "Templates"];
  var html = $("#MyTemplate").parseTemplate(data);
  $("#divContainer").html(html);
}
</script>
```

The `divContainer` can be any html element (div, span, etc.). I usually store the templates in separate files and load them on the server:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
var templateContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Templates/MyTemplate.htm"));
</script>
...

<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/template">
<%= templateContent %>
</script>
```

This way is very easy to edit the templates. It's not perfect, but I never have to worry about debugging long strings of HTML.

Comment: Jquery Template helps me alot. Thank you.